# How to align individual table column headers in JavaFXML with CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

I would like to make some column headers left-aligned and others right-aligned, for example:

```
|hdr1   |hdr2  |    hdr3|    hdr4|
```

In my css stylesheet I have tried:

```
#colHeadingLeft .column-header{
  -fx-alignment: CENTER_LEFT;
}

#colHeadingRight .column-header{
  -fx-alignment: CENTER_RIGHT;
}
```

In the SceneBuilder, Java FX CSS, I set id to each of the column heading tags defined above. However, this has no effect at all. I get instead get every header center aligned like this:

```
|  hdr1  |  hdr2  |  hdr3  |  hdr4 |
```

I have tried a large number of experiments to get this working without success and I wonder if it is actually possible to style columns individually in a tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the alignment for the child label of the column header. Furthermore I recommend using [style classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumnBase.html#getStyleClass--) to achieve this goal.

The following `ComboBox` allows you to choose the alignment of a `TableColumn column`:

```
column.getStyleClass().add("center");

ComboBox<String> styleChoice = new ComboBox<>();
styleChoice.getItems().addAll("left", "center", "right");
styleChoice.valueProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> column.getStyleClass().set(column.getStyleClass().size() - 1, newValue));
```

```css
.column-header.center .label {
    -fx-alignment: center;
}

.column-header.left .label {
    -fx-alignment: center-left;
}

.column-header.right .label {
    -fx-alignment: center-right;
}
```

The combobox is just an example of changing the alignment programmatically. Of course you could add the appropriate style classes to the `TableColumn`s:

```
column1.getStyleClass().add("left");
column2.getStyleClass().add("left");
column3.getStyleClass().add("right");
column4.getStyleClass().add("right");
```

Ids imho shouldn't be used, since you're applying the same style to multiple columns. (Using ids would require you to add a seperate selector for every single column in the CSS.)